# Where can I find the list of attributes name?

Tags: java, nio, file-attributes

I am just wondering if there is a list of attributes name to be referred when using the following:

> However, you can set a DOS attribute using the setAttribute(Path,
>   String, Object, LinkOption...) method, as follows:
>
> Path file = ...; Files.setAttribute(file, "dos:hidden", true);

In this case the `.isHidden()` method is referred as `hidden`, what about `isReadOnly()`? I have tried `dos:readOnly` and other combination, however without achieving the result wanted.
Dou you know any link which has a list of those attribute "reference"?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.kodejava.org/how-do-i-set-the-value-of-file-attributes/

```
//
// Set a new file attributes.
//
Files.setAttribute(file, "dos:archive", false);
Files.setAttribute(file, "dos:hidden", false);
Files.setAttribute(file, "dos:readonly", false);
Files.setAttribute(file, "dos:system", false);
```

Comment: forget about it: "This attribute is often used to indicate that the file is a component of the operating system."

Comment: I was just about to reply, and that's about exactly what I was going to say. Honestly, I don't really know when anyone would need that command.